# Multi-Select ComboBox Set Selected Property True

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to select the `ID` from `Persons_Form!ID` in the multi-select combox on `Form_Load()`.

The code below executes fine.  The message box does pop u;p however the value is always false, and the checkbox is not ticked in the combo box even though is set it to True.

My expected behavior would be for it to be checked after the code runs, and return True in the MsgBox.  What do I need to change in order to get my expected behavior?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If ID.Value >= 0 Then
        Beep
    Else
        Beep
        With person
            .SetFocus
            For x = Abs(.ColumnHeads) To (.ListCount - 1)
                If (.ItemData(x) Like Forms!Persons_Form!ID.Value) Then
                    .Selected(x) = True
                    MsgBox (.Selected(x))
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a code break at the "If (.ItemData(x) Like..." line, and then hover your mouse over both ".ItemData(x)" and "Forms!Persons_Form!ID.Value".  This will tell you what Access thinks those 2 values are.  Then press F8 to step through the code, and check those values for each loop.  You'll probably see right away what you did wrong, or what Access doesn't like.

Comment: Access 'Likes' the code.  The code inside the IF statement does execute at the correct time.  x is assigned to the correct index.  Selected(x) does return the current state of the checkbox and the assignment statement does not cause an error.  However right after the assignment statement Selected(x) still returns false.

Comment: So you're saying it hits the line that sets .Selected(x) = true, and it still pops up a box that says .Selected(x) = false?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what it does.

Comment: what type of object is `person`?

Comment: person is a Multi-Select ComboBox

Comment: Pablo, This is a multi-select box.  The ListIndex is listed as: You can use the ListIndex property to determine which item is selected in a combo box.  This does not seem that it will help assign a item selected status?  Can you explain further.

Comment: I have deleted my comment

Comment: For clarification, your first line of code references "ID.Value", then later you reference "Forms!Persons_Form!ID.Value".  Where/what is the first reference - this form or is it supposed supposed to be another form - is it a textbox or what?

Comment: ID.Value and Forms!Persons_Form!ID.Value refer to the same thing, I should have used the same for both for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment with my low rep yet. But for the person object what does the  .MultiSelect property show? If it's zero you can't set multiple selections to true.

Answer (score 1):

You have to trouble shoot.  Start simple.  Work up.  Leave off `SetFocus`, for starters!

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    person.Selected(1) = True
    MsgBox (person.Selected(1))
End Sub
```

Also, add a Boolean variable.  Using a variable can clear up many a mess.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim booSelected As Boolean
    person.Selected(1) = True
    booSelected = person.Selected(1)
    MsgBox booSelected
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow when I get into work.  My apologies for the lack of attention to this question as of late.  Thank You,

Comment: I wonder what happened.  Did you ever get the function to work the way you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to replicate the problem on my computer.
Once I get it to fail, then I can work on fixing it.
I would agree with Wayne, in that probably there is a

Persons_Form  that has an ID

and a

Me (form) that has the Form_Load,

Which form has the person combobox? and 
Where is that set of combos populated?
What triggers this Form_Load?
These things are not obivious from the code fragment,
Could you post a runable fragment?

I would use Northwind to populate my person combos,
so there is no need to supply any private data.
Yet it would be nice to know what type of pattern is in ID
and what type of ItemData would be in the combobox.

tkx,

3/15 20:40 Sat nite 
Thanks for the increased visibility on the problem.
Now I have questions with the tables, so
please run DatabaseTools / Documenter /

```
on Tables:   Person  and Report
and set Include-for-fields to the last radio(all items)

and on Forms: "FormA"
and set Include-for-Sections-and-Controls  both Names&Properties
```

You could then put the output Table info 
and just the "person" control info into a txt file
and upload it to somewhere 
  like  http://www.filedropper.com/free-file-hosting.php
and put the resulting url into stackover next comment.

tkx

Comment: The scenario is that there are two forms.  "FormA" contains a "Multiselect" "Combobox" (called "person") and it is assigned to a Table "Report" Column: "Persons"(MultiValue Field) witch has a many-to-many relationship with table "Person" column "ID".  The user clicks a button on "FormA" that loads "FormB".  "FormB" Allows the user to create a new person in the "Person" Table.  "FormB" "OnClose" will refresh the data in "FormA" and then automatically select the entry in the "person" "multiselect combobox" that matches the ID of the new "person" just created on "FormB"